# TryParse while CellValidating

Tags: c#, tryparse

Before leaving cell i want to check if user inputed number or some other characters so i use TryParse and here is my code:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        int n;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.FormattedValue.ToString(), out n);
        if (isNumeric)
        {
            //Code
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

In both cases it gives me fault, it doesn't matter if i am inputing numbers or any other character.

Comment: use the event args. that is what they are for.  you should be testing `e.Value`

Comment: And you should consider if you need to handle an empty cell: `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to check current cell value with eventArgs so code looks like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out n);
    if (isNumeric)
    {
        //Code
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```